Redirect domain (without hosting plan) using just nameservers
I have a domain registered at Mochahost with no hosting plan (abc.com). I want to redirect visitors to this domain to a new different website / domain hosted elsewehere (123.com).
The Mochahost DNS settings only allow me access to nameservers settings -- no DNS records, no cPanel, no domain forwarding or redirect settings.
Assuming I need to update the nameservers setttings of abc.com to point to the new site (123.com)... Can anybody shed some light on this? TIA

DNS servers alone cannot redirect domains, so what the title of your question asks for is not possible.  NS record point to DNS hosting which in turn has to point to web hosting which in turn issues redirects.

Does the destination website allow multiple domains to point to it (they may be called "aliases")? Are you sure Mochahost does not allow editing DNS records and does not allow domain forwarding either? That would be highly unusual.

Have you contacted the Mochahost registrar directly to ask about this?
According to Mochahost's domain advertising at:
https://mochahost.com/domains
They offer "Free web forwarding" where they "Redirect traffic from your domain to a preferred website, making online navigation and accessibility easier than ever."
So... I'd ask them directly if they can help.  It really seems they are both capable & even legally bound to do so as a result of their pretty explicit advertising.
If this is somehow unsuccessful, please update accordingly here.  If we reach that point, I would like to ask some further questions if I may be so bold.
To reach their support, you can go through the Mochahost site, or I think that you can directly go to:
https://stablechat.mysecurecloudhost.com/widget?website_token=o2Gc8GQRskiHn6mYU7btdwQT
(I'd just go through their site though.)

The short answer is "you can't" [redirect a domain using just nameservers]
Assuming you use HTTPS and are talking about redirecting web hosting -  there are a lot of moving parts you need to get working to redirect a domain name.
The first thing is you need authorative nameservers which say where to point the domain name.   As you can only change nameserver settings but not add DNS records, you will need to find nameservers you can use to set up the zone file for your domain name.  I've never looked at it, but you may be able to do this for free using Cloudflares free Authorative DNS (https://www.cloudflare.com/application-services/products/dns/) if the issue is one of $$$
Once you have the nameservers set, you need to configure these to a web server which will handle the request (generally using A and/or CNAME records.  If you don't know anything about CNAME records, use A records where possible).    A key thing to know is that the web server needs to know the domain name so it can identify how to route the request.   You may be able to use cloudflare for this as well, and set up page rules for this - or, if your web server will allow you to add this association on their web server, you can use that.  You could also point to another web server which just advised the web client to do a redirect.   point being, the web server needs to be involved in this process.
The last bit of the puzzle is an SSL certificate.  Because most websites are HTTPS, they require an https certficate which includes the names of the sites it handles.  This can often be done fore free using lets-encrypt or other mechanisms, but does have some requirements (like the DNS pointing to the web server, and the web server knowing to create/maintain the cert).  This can't be done using just DNS.    It is very likely that again, Cloudflare can cover this for you if you use their services.
